# How to read a json key which has space in c#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

This is the sample json

```json
{
    "custom_data": {
        "Form Name": "Test OSP",
        "School": "Hamilton High School",
    }
}
```

I'm using .Net Core for front end without model classes.

I'm Able to get full json value in api call then stored in Jobject . problem comes when I  try to access the specific key "Form Name"
from the Json response

If I try to access the `Form Name` like this

```cs
dynamic FormName = reportResults.custom_data["Form Name"];
```

I'm getting error like this

> `((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)Transactions.custom_data["Form Name"]).First`' threw an exception of type
> Error processing 'variables' request. Unknown Error: 0x89720013

'((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)FormName).Last' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Is there is any other way to read it .. ? Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you currently reading it?

Comment: _"not able to read it"_ how are you trying to read it? Please include the code (in the question) you have used so far.

Comment: You have tagged both .NET and .NET Core, could you clarify which versions you are using?

Comment: The exception does not match your code. Please show your actual code. On a side note, why do you bother with Tasks if all you do is immediately throwing away all benefits they provide, with `.Wait` [and `.Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)?

Comment: Probably because they are using `HttpClient` and have no choice but to use the async versions, but can't be bothered to make their code properly async. I agree they should be using `await` rather than `.Result` though

Comment: I'm Able to get all json value in the above api call. problem comes when i  try to access the specific key "Form Name"

Comment: Blocking asynchronous methods the way you do is a bug to begin with. The error you posted has nothing to do with the question's code either. Post the actual *full* exception text and the code that raised it. You can get the full exception text with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on the `Copy Details` link button in the exception popup while debugging

Comment: `Task.Run(async() => await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject >()` is another bug - `ReadAsAsync` already returns a Task. What's the point of using `Task.Run`, especially when you block it with `.Result`? You should clean up your code, remove all blocking calls and post the actual code that throws.

Comment: `reportResults.custom_data` will raise a compilation error, not an exception, unless `reportResults` is `dynamic`. In your code, it's a `JObject`. This isn't the actual code that throws

Comment: yes  reportResults  is dynamic

Comment: Then post the  *real* code. What you posted can't produce that error. I **strongly** suggest cleaning up the code first though. It looks like you're adding code at random trying to get things to work. You don't need the blocking calls, `Task.Run` or even `dynamic` to just reads some properties from a JObject by name. All this code could be just 3 lines

Comment: And now that you *removed* the HttpClient calls, the question is simply meaningless. It's impossible to answer because all the actual code is missing and the error has nothing to do with the code that remains

Comment: Once you have a JObject you can access all properties by name, like a dictionary: `myObject["custom_data"]["Form Name"]`. You don't need to make it dynamic. That's not what the exception complains about though. If you parsed the string wtih `dynamic obj=JObject.Parse(...);` the call `obj.custom_data["Form Name"]` would work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no any problem with reading properties with whitespace in name:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
var reportResults = JObject.Parse(jsonFromQuestion);
var name = reportResults["custom_data"]["Form Name"].ToString(); // Test OSP
```

Comment: The OP added a comment that `reportResults` is `dynamic`. Even so, the code works

Answer (score 3):

you can use [JsonProperty] attribute for your classes

```
Data reportResults= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
var  formName = reportResults.custom_data.FormName;
```

classes

```
 public class CustomData
    {
        [JsonProperty("Form Name")]
        public string FormName { get; set; }
        public string School { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public CustomData custom_data { get; set; }
    }
```